# Why my arrays properties are not being detected when I instantiate this class?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I've created this class below, and when I instantiate it in another class, it simply do not see my arrays, only the `otherProp`. And when I try to push stuff into the array, I get an error because the `myArray1` or 2 is undefined. What's wrong with this arrays? I have tried creating the arrays in other ways, including"any[]" and initializing them as empty, but it didn't work either.

```
export class MyModel{
    myArray1: Array<{dias: Array<number>, amount: number}> //<[number[], number]>;
    otherProp: number;                   
    myArray2: Array<{month: number, amount: number}>//<[number, number]> //myArray2, month

    Constructor(){        
        this.otherProp= 0;
        this.myArray1= new Array<{dias: Array<number>, amount: number}>();
        this.myArray2 = new Array<{month: number, amount: number}>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Constructor` should be lowercase. So it never gets called. Since `otherProp` is a primitive, it automatically get initialized to the default which is 0

Comment: It worked! Man! I can't believe I didn't see that!! This is the result of programing being really sleepy!!! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Please refrain from cursing. Notice I edited that out from your post ;-)